# What is the meaning of 'should have got forgotten'?

Tags: meaning, get-passive

I came across the following passage:

> In August that year, Baleson wrote to his friend Francis Galton: “I am
>   writing to ask you to look up the paper of Mendl [sic] [which] seems to
>   me one of the most remarkable investigations yet made on heredity and
>   it is extraordinary that it should have got forgotten.”

I attempted to interpret it by myself but the conclusion that i draw contradicts with itself. I consulted to many teachers. Most of them say that, it denotes that it is surprise people didn't remember and i should replace got with "been".  Others says that, the mentioned information is now being remembered

> it is extraordinary that it should have got forgotten

From this image:

[image]

Comment: It's an error.  No biggie.

Comment: Sir could you be more spesific? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to *type out* the sentence with its surrounding context (an image file is not an acceptable replacement for this) and also include the title of the source and a link to the source. Second, it is not an error, it is the use of the so-called "get passive," where "should have got forgotten" is equal to "should have been forgotten" or perhaps "should have become forgotten".

Comment: It's from the book called" The gene and the intimate history". For its my first time here, i dont knkw exactly how to use this

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to type out the sentence with its surrounding context (an image file is not an acceptable replacement for this)

Comment: This might be an archaic usage, it's not correct now.

Comment: @Barmar Depending in context, it’s not archaic. Luggage *gets forgotten* from time to time, for example.

Comment: @Lawrence After "should have", shouldn't it be "gotten"?

Comment: @Barmar English can be surprising. Both *got* and *gotten* sound awkward in the snippet, but perhaps an appropriate context would change that. The OP needs a complete sentence in the quote.

Comment: @Lawrence He originally posted a screenshot of the entire paragraph. Someone edited it out.

Comment: There was an error.  It might be a missing "been", or it could be any of a handful of other slip-ups or brain farts.  Impossible to be more precise than that.

Comment: @HotLicks No, it’s merely a *get*-passive not a *be*-passive.